# Problem with vector of objects/pointers (Implementing composite design pattern)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement the composite design pattern for a uni practical, I have an abstract base class DocumentComponent, and two classes that inherit from it, TextBody and Word. It's supposed to represent a sentence that can contain additional sentences and/or words. My problem arises when I try to implement the TextBody class, which has functions addComponent and Print. They are supposed to add a new DocumentComponent object to the vector using push_back, and to call the print function of each element in the vector, respectively. I'm storing my objects in a vector of DocumentComponent objects/pointers called container, and I can only get one of the two to work at a time (by changing my vector to either be a vector of pointers or a vector of objects). If I do the former my print function works but not my addComponent function, and if the latter the situation is reversed. Here's my code:

documentComponent.h:

```
class DocumentComponent
{   
    public:
        virtual void removeComponent(int index){}
        virtual void addComponent(DocumentComponent& comp){}
        virtual void print()=0;
};
```

textBody.h:

```
class TextBody : public DocumentComponent
{
    public:
        TextBody();
        virtual void addComponent(DocumentComponent& comp);
        virtual void print();
    private:
        vector<DocumentComponent*> container;
};
```

textBody.cpp:

```
void TextBody::addComponent(DocumentComponent& comp)
{
    container.push_back(&comp);
}

void TextBody::print()
{
    if (container.size() == 0)
        return;
    for_each(container.begin(), container.end(),mem_fun_ref(&DocumentComponent::print));
}
```

I get the error message

"Cannot initialize 'DocumentComponent &' with 'DocumentComponent *' in function for_each

which I understand is because I'm giving it a pointer when it wants a reference, but changing my vector to a vector of objects results in

"Cannot create instance of abstract class 'DocumentComponent'"

in my addComponent function

Answer (score 3):

When you say:

```
void TextBody::addComponent(DocumentComponent& comp)
{
    container.push_back(&comp);
}
```

is the thing referred to dynamically allocated? If not, you will probably have problems, and if it is you should simply pass a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

[mem_fun_ref()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/741a5f2d(VS.80).aspx) calls a member on a reference object, [mem_fun()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtc0dy7y.aspx) calls a method through a pointer.

Therefore you will need to use mem_fun() like so:
**textbody.cpp**

```
void TextBody::print()
{
    if (container.size() == 0)
        return;
    for_each(container.begin(), container.end(),mem_fun(&DocumentComponent::print));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you shoud use `mem_fun()` instead of `mem_fun_ref(),` it will work with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys, I ended up using a for loop but changed it back to the for_each with mem_fun instead of mem_fun_ref after seeing your answers, works like a charm